# How to detect connection of usb device to trigger a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

My end goal is this:

when a specific usb drive gets connected to the system, I need to delete a file from that device and then copy a file from a different directory into the device, then eject the usb drive. All the file copying and such can be done through a shell script, but how could I trigger the script upon connection of  the usb drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a line like this in a file in /etc/udev/rules.d:

```
KERNEL=="sd*", ATTRS{vendor}=="Yoyodyne", ATTRS{model}=="XYZ42", ATTRS{serial}=="123465789", RUN+="/pathto/script"
```

Add a clause like `NAME="subdir/mydisk%n"` if you want to use a custom entry path under `/dev`.
Run `udevadm info -a -n sdb` to see what attributes you can match against (`attribute=="value`"; replace `sdb` by the device name automatically assigned to the disk, corresponding to the new entry created in `/dev` when you plug it in). Note that you can use `ATTRS` clauses from any one stanza: you can pick any stanza, but the `ATTRS` clauses must all come from the same stanza, you can't mix and match. You can mix `ATTRS` clauses with other types of clauses listed in a different stanza.
[from](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28577/229893)